# matching a @import declaration with ASTMatchers

Tags: objective-c, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, libtooling, clang-ast-matchers

I'm trying to match objc `@import` declarations using AST-matchers for a custom tool I'm creating; I'm using `Result.Context->local_imports()` but although I have `@import` statements in my source code and I'm passing the `fmodules` flag, the iterator returned from `local_imports` is always empty. Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Objective-C, so I don't really know much about how it works. I tried to dump AST for hello world example and, first of all, it's huge (!), and there is no single `ImportDecl` in there.

Comment: hey @ValeriySavchenko, thanks for looking into it, did you pass  the flag `-fmodules`  to the dump command?

Comment: yes, that was the reason. Now I can see `ImportDecl`. Did you try traversing all top-level declarations instead of using `local_imports`?

Comment: hey @ValeriySavchenko, I tried using a RecursiveASTVisitor but that didn't help :( somehow there are no `ImportDecl` for the translation unit

Comment: How do you run your clang tool? What happens if you dump AST for `TrasnslationUnitDecl`?

Comment: I'm running it just like you wuold run `clang-format` or any other tool. I'm also including the `-fmodules` flag. I just dumped the `TranslationUnitDecl` and interestingly enough the `ImportDecl` is also not returned... why would the clang `ast-dump` command behave different than my tool?  @ValeriySavchenko

Comment: Just to be clear: you run it somewhat like this: `clang-tool test.m -- -fmodules`?

Comment: exactly @ValeriySavchenko, but dumping wont return `ImportDecl` :( doing `clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fmodules test.m` does

Comment: One advice here left is to generate `compile_commands.json` and see what happens when Clang takes care of its own command line arguments.

Comment: thanks @ValeriySavchenko I will consider that.